# Why touching a slider that is on top of a SCNView moves the camera underneath on iOS 8/Swift?

Tags: swift, ios8, uislider, scenekit

Using Xcode 6 GM, I created a new project based on the Game template using SceneKit and Swift. Then I dragged a slider onto the SCNView. Now in the simulation, when I move the slider, the slider moves (as expected) but the camera moves as well (like if I was simply touching the screen). I'm not an experienced iOS developer but I never had this problem in the past. Did I forget to do something? Did anything change recently in the default behaviour of sliders? It looks more like a bug to me. If you add a slider, you want to control only this slider, not what is underneath.

Anyone can help me there or confirm the issue? Sorry if it's the answer is very simple. I googled my problem but could not find anything.

Answer (score 0):

There is a property on the scene called `allowsCameraControl`, and if that is set to `true` then the panning will control the camera. It's probably on by default in the game template.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I can't control my camera (with allowsCameraControl set to true) AND have sliders in my scene? In my opinion I should be able to do both. So I have to set allowsCameraControl to false and add the control of my camera by adding gestures recognizers manually?? What's the usual way to do it?

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure if you can combine built in camerq control with other controls. Possibly if you subclass the slider and override hittesting. It's not hard to make your own camera controls though. Ray Wenderlich has a somewhat related tutorial that could be useful. http://www.raywenderlich.com/12667/how-to-rotate-a-3d-object-using-touches-with-opengl

Comment: Yep, it seems that combining the built-in camera controls with sliders is just not possible. Which it's a bit disappointing in my opinion. It does not make much sense in my mind. The position of the finger should only be caught by the slider and not the camera underneath. But yes, ok, I guess I'll have to implement the camera control myself then. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Perhaps you can try turning off camera control on the fly, while the slider is changing values?